# Does publishing a research chapter in a book advance my academic career?

Tags: publications

I am a soon-to-graduate PhD student.

Recently, I received an e-mail from an academic society,
which was a call for research chapters.
I have quoted the contents of the e-mail below,
stripping out the unimportant details:

> We are editing a new volume titled {THE TITLE}
>   for Springer International Series in {THE FIELD OF RESEARCH}.
>   We are inviting high quality research chapters
>   that would open new research stream in {THE SUBFIELD OF RESEARCH}.
>   Interested scholars are requested to send us
>   their chapter proposals in the form of an abstract (500-1000 words) by {THE DATE}.

**Questions:**

1. How does publishing a research chapter in a book
   advance my academic career
   compared to publishing a journal article?
2. Does submitting work to a journal article
   preclude submitting the same work as a research chapter in a book?

Comment: Also see [What are the things one should consider when invited to contribute a book chapter?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19133/what-are-the-things-one-should-consider-when-invited-to-contribute-a-book-chapte)

Comment: Hi I Like to Code, the first question you ask is a duplicate of another question. If your second question is not addressed by the linked question (or any other), you should ask it as a new question.